# Generate UML from Flex Projects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, uml

Are there any good tools to generate UML class diagrams using the source code from a Flex Builder project?  I have been trying IntelliJ but for some reason it generates the inherited class structure from the SDK and not everything below my main app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [UML4AS - UML for ActionScript and Flex](http://www.uml4as.com).

Comment: I was looking at it earlier, but they have not released the alpha product, so there is nothing for me to test with.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look on the following program:

Commercial:

http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/12/13/5963_aboutvisualp.html

Free:
[Using StarUML to Generate ActionScript 3.0](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/starumltoas3/)

**Edit: 29 May**

http://www.uml4as.com/flower-platform/ the alpha version can be download now.

Comment: Thanx.  Enterprise architect generated a class diagram, but only the actionscript.  Nothing from the MXML.  Visual Patadigm does not appear to support MXML or actionscript.

Comment: Visual Patadigm do support actionscript.  As I know there is no program support MXML, but not very sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option for now is to use [Crocus Modeller, UML for Flex & AS3](http://crocusmodeller.com)